# Why can't I use multiplie verbboxes?

Tags: verbatim, stackengine

I am writing some documentation for a testing framework I am using at work and I use verb boxes to show code and add comments/captions that pertain specifically to that code. But I am getting the error:

`Undefined control sequence.
 ...{Get Current Date} from the \testbf 
                                                  {DateTime} library, you ca...
l.65 ...fore calling the function.}}}{\theverbbox}`

For some reason, I cannot have more than one verbbox? If I remove the box that generates the error, the error simply occurs at the next verb box. Is there something wrong with the way I have written this, or is it an underlying error?

```
\begin{verbbox}
*** Settings ***
Documentation     A resource file with reusable keywords and variables. #This is the description of the resource file

Library           Selenium2Library
Library           FakerLibrary    WITH NAME    faker
Library           DateTime    WITH NAME    DateTime
\end{verbbox}
\stackinset{c}{}{t}{-.1cm}{\textcolor{red}{\sffamily\tiny\parbox{2.2in}{
 The \textit{Library} keyword tells Robot that it needs to make sure that this is installed and available to use, otherwise it will tell you that importing the library failed. Selenium is needed in \textbf{all} of our resource files.}}}{\theverbbox}\\[1\baselineskip]

In the above example I have imported two optional libraries (faker and DateTime). faker creates random data that can be used to populate fields, DateTime allows me to get the current date among other helpful functions. I have also used the \textit{WITH NAME} argument, I have done so because it will make it more obvious to anyone new to Robot Framework tests which functions are being called from these libraries. I did \textbf{not} do this for Selenium because Selenium is the base of most Robot Framework functionality and would not serve to clarify the function of our tests.

Example of library keywords:
\begin{verbbox}
\${DATE}=   | DateTime.Get Current Date | result_format=%Y-%m-%d
\end{verbbox}
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.1cm}{\textcolor{red}{\sffamily\tiny\parbox{2.2in}{ This variable uses the function \textit{Get Current Date} from the \testbf{DateTime} library, you can tell because it uses the prefix that I defined in my earlier example before calling the function.}}}{\theverbbox}
```

Comment: `\testbf `  you presumably meant `\textbf` ?

Comment: I am a collosal moron, I'm gonna flag this Q for deletion..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to a mistyped command

Comment: I flagged it earlier and left a comment of "unhelpful for future users, question was off topic". Just waiting for a mod to clean up :)

Answer (score 2):

The error message is nothing to do with verbatim

```
Undefined control sequence. ...{Get Current Date} from the \testbf
```

`\testbf` should presumably be `\textbf`